# Are OSGI bundles running on multiple cores

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

In a multi core cpu system, do osgi bundles running on different cores? 
So, bundle A is running on core 1, bundle B is running on core 2 and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundles are libraries.  They can be passive, in which case they use the threads which call them or they can create their own threads.

In any Java program, you cannot say where code will be running unless you have placed your threads and the code they call very carefully.

Your bundles could share the same threads or use different threads depending on how they are used. Those thread could use the same core, or different cores.